# Munkres - Analysis on manifolds Lemma 16.2 proof

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading through this proof but after it, it's remarked that a point x of the boundary of A intersects infinitely many of the cubes from the constructed collection.

I don't understand why is he saying that, if one of the conditions is precisely (2) that each of the rectangles is contained in an element of the collection of open sets, and therefore they cannot intersect the boundary of the union.

I'd like to know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote as follows:

> a point $x$ of the boundary of $A$ intersects infinitely many of the cubes from the constructed collection.

But the author wrote:

> Each neighborhood of a point $x$ of the boundary of $A$ intersects infinitely many of the cubes from the constructed collection.